# What is the difference in Yocto - meta-extsdk-toolchain vs do_populate_sdk_ext for core image?

Tags: embedded, yocto, bitbake

In Yocto [manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html) it is explained that to create Yocto extensible SDK (eSDK) we need to run:

```
$ bitbake <image> -c populate_sdk_ext
```

For example:

```
$ bitbake core-image-full-cmdline -c populate_sdk_ext
```

But then - what do we need the bitbake recipe named `meta-extsdk-toolchain` for?

Answer (score 3):

After talking to guys on Yocto IRC...

That is what should be used to produce eSDK:

```
bitbake core-image-full-cmdline -c populate_sdk_ext
```

That is what should be used to produce SDK (regular SDK):

```
bitbake core-image-full-cmdline -c populate_sdk
```

The `meta-extsdk-toolchain` recipe does not need to be used.